# how to create selected item and input what item is

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i wanna learn how to search something from database, and it's work, here the code

```
<fieldset>
<form action="" method="POST">
    By Round Id : <input id="input-round" type="text" name="name" size="15"/><br/><br/>
    By Player Id : <input id="input-player-id" type="text" name="player" size="15"/><br/><br/>
    <input id="btn-form-close" type="button" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btn-form-close").click(function(){
$('#view-form').html('');
});

$('#input-round').keyup(function(){
    var name = $('#input-round').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('account/look_search_history_round');?>",
            data:'nama='+name,
            success:function(html){
                $('#view-list-round-id').html(html);
            }
        });
});
$('#input-player-id').keyup(function(){
    var player = $('#input-player-id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('account/look_search_history_player');?>",
            data:'nama='+player,
            success:function(html){
                $('#view-list-round-id').html(html);
            }
        });
});
```

but i wanna create something like option can be selected, so i can selected search `By Round Id` or `By player Id`. but i don't have any idea how to accomplish that. what i get is select that option

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option> By Round Id </option>
    <option> By Player Id</option>
</select>
```

but what about input? can someone give me example, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all now i get it, here the code i want it

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   Search by
   <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option id="roundId"> Rounds Id</option>
      <option id="playerId"> Player Id</option>
   </select>
     : <input id="input" type="text" name="input" size="15"/><br/><br/>
   <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" />
</form>
```

jquery function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn-form-close").click(function(){
    $('#view-form').html('');
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var data = {
                        'select' : $("#select").val(),
                        'input' : $("#input").val(),
                    };
            //alert ($("#input").val());
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo site_url('account/look_search_history');?>",
                data:data,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#view-list-round-id').html(html);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

and about controller is here

```
public function look_search_history(){
        if($_POST['input']){
            $select = $_POST['select'];
            $input = $_POST['input'];

            if ($select == "Rounds Id"){
                $data['tbl_bet_spot'] = $this->login_model->select_by_round($input)->result();
                $this->load->view('roulette/view_search_history', $data);
            }else if ($select == "Player Id"){
                $data['tbl_bet_spot'] = $this->login_model->select_by_player($input)->result();
                $this->load->view('roulette/view_search_history', $data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you may want to include in the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   Search by
   <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option id="roundId"> By Round Id </option>
      <option id="playerId"> By Player Id</option>
   </select>
     Id : <input id="input-round" type="text" name="name" size="15"/><br/><br/>
   <input id="btn-form-close" type="button" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

then send the selected option to backend to process

```
$('#input-round').keyup(function(){
    var name = $('#input-round').val();
    var choice = $('#sel1 option:selected').val()
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('account/look_search_history_round');?>",
            data:'nama='+name+'&choice='+choice, //process this choice in backend..
            success:function(html){
                $('#view-list-round-id').html(html);
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not given value for option

change it like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
<option value="1" data-id="2"> By Round Id </option>
<option value="2" data-id="1"> By Player Id</option>
 <option value="3" data-id="2"> By Round Id </option>
</select>
```

and the jquery function

```
$('#sel1').change(function(){
var player = $(this).val();

var PR_id = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-id');
  if(PR_id == 1)
   {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo site_url('account/look_search_history_player');?>",
        data:'nama='+player,
        success:function(html){
            $('#view-list-round-id').html(html);
        }
    });
   }
   else if(PR_id ==2)
  {
      //next ajax call
  }
 });
```

Comment: but how about this function `account/look_search_history_player ` ? each selected using different function there is 2 function `account/look_search_history_round` and `account/look_search_history_player`

Comment: you need to handle it in server side coding

Comment: if you know the round id of each player then you can handle by giving data-id for option